# Why can't I write to a file that I open in python?

Tags: python

I opened the python interpreter and tried to write to a file I was reading at the same time:

```
file = open("foo.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(0, 3):
    file.write(lines[0])
```

However, python issued an error that noted I had a bad file handler when I tried to execute `file.write(lines[0])`. Why can't I write the first line of a file to the file itself?

Comment: `file = open("foo.txt", "r+");` and it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to write to a file, it's necessary to open the file in *write* or *read/write* mode

```
file = open("foo.txt", "r+")  # reading and writing to file
```

or

```
file = open("foo.txt", "w")   # writing only to file
```

If you open a file and don't specify a mode, it's in *read* mode by default, so you had opened your file for "read", but were trying to "write" to it.

See [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) Python Docs for more information. @Mizuho also suggested this page about [Python File IO](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) which has a very nice summary of the various modes available.